# Data Management Techniques for Rapid Input (iOS 5)

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite, core-data, ios5

Hello I'm new to this forum (signed up today... have always used it for reference in the past though) and new to iOS development (6 months), but not a new programmer.  I'm creating an app in iOS 5 for iPad that will require the user to rapidly input and update data (mainly adding, subtracting , changing BOOL states, etc... with time between events less than 2 seconds at times) for numerous objects.  It is currently designed to use a SQL database, but worry that with rapid entries and updating that the database will get corrupt if it is not opened and closed rapidly enough.  Any suggestions or lessons learned from iOS/iPad/iPhone experience?  Is SQLite a preferred method for rapid input or should I switch to something else?  Thanks and taker easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core data handles all of the database connections for you. Changing properties on your managed objects doesn't involve a connection to the database every time, it just updates the objects in memory. The database is updated when you save the context and probably periodically in the background - the point is, you don't have to worry about it.

Don't code around a problem that doesn't exist - write your app using core data, and if you get database corruption problems, investigate then. But I doubt you will have anything to worry about on that score.

Comment: Thanks for the response... after much reading of the documentation late last night I started leaning in that direction as well!